# Check if a variable belongs to an enum value

Tags: objective-c, ios, enums

Is there any way to assign a set of values to an enum and check wether a variable has its value in that enum in objective-c. 
Something like getting the index of an object in an array if the object is present in an array. I want to give a common behavior, when certain indexes(may not be in order) tapped in my table view, want to avoid if-ing all the indexes, hope I can use enum style.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C, like most programming languages, doesn't provide a "type membership" test for primitive types - just for object types (e.g. `isKindOfClass:`) - so using an `enum` won't solve your problem.

However given that you are thinking of an `enum` in the first place it sounds like you have a small fixed set of values you wish to check for. In that case you can just use a static array, e.g. something like:

```
static NSUInteger indices[] = { 2, 42, 57 };
```

The number of values in such an array is given by `sizeof(indices) / sizeof(NSUInteger` and you can write a simple loop or binary search to test for membership.

If you wish to use objects then `NSSet` is a good choice, if the numbers will vary during execution then `NSMutableSet`. E.g.

```
NSSet *indices = [NSSet setWithObjects:@2, @42, @57, nil];
```

and you test for membership using `member:`:

```
if ([indices member:@indexToTest] != nil) ...
```

(Note: unlike `NSArray` the specification for `containsObject:` for `NSSet` does **not** say it uses `isEqual:`, hence the use of `member:` here.)

Comment: Helpful answer, i think i should create a set of indexpaths and check if the current selected indexpath belongs to the set and perform suitable actions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use an `enum` for that, because you can't enumerate them or call sth. like `contains` on them. If I understand your correctly I think the straight forward way to do that would be to just use an `NSArray` to store the indices you care about. Say you want to recognize the indices 2,6 and 14:

```
NSArray *indices = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @2, @6, @14, nil];
```

(The `@` is necessary because an NSArray can only store objects. The `@` turns the integers into `NSNumber` instances.

Then to check if the currently selected index is in it you use:

```
int indexToCheck = ...;
BOOL indexIsInArray = [index containsObject:@(indexToCheck)];
```

If your looking for a more 'fancy' (and faster) way to that, you could use bit operations (again using 2,6 and 14 as example):

```
int indices = 1 << 2 | 1 << 6 | 1 << 14;
```

and then to check:

```
int indexToCheck = ...;
BOOL isValid = (1 << indexToCheck) & indices;
```

where `isValid` is true when the `indexToCheck` in one of your `indices`.

Comment: easy mistake to make given the name, but `containsObject:` does a *value* comparison by calling `isEqual:` and does not do reference comparison. So if using an array it is just `[indices containsObject:@(indexToCheck)]`

Answer (score 0):

No, internally enums are based on integers, and the mapping happens at compile time. So you need a specific check for every enum type (if they are consecutive numbers, a ">" and "<" check will do).